# Randomly Appearing Popups In Unity3D

Tags: unity-game-engine

How can i make an image to randomly appear  while in-game in Unity3D ? It will serve as my popup advertisements for my game. I want to have ads without using AdMobs or any other plugins.

Comment: I have tried googling ways to put ads in a unity3d game. But all i have read is using plugins like AdMobs and UnityAds. So i decided to just use GUI Images and serve it as popups while in game. But I don't know how to make it randomly appear while in runtime .

Comment: Let me just say that your user experience might (will?) suffer tremendously if you're randomly interrupting the user with ads. Consider only placing them at logical pauses in the user flow (eg. Between levels, upon death, etc.) so they're not as off-putting to the user.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how you plan to display your images. You could write a script to randomly Enable a GUI Image, then have the GUI Image become disables after a specified time is over or by a button click (like a "X" symbol or close button).

My recommendation would be some mix of the following:

1. Create an UI Image GameObject. Use this as the main Advertisement GameObject.
2. Create a script to set this gameobject active/inactive randomly throughout the game. Place this script on an object in the hierarchy that will exist throughout the game.
3. Create a script that will be your advertisement handler. Attach this to your UI GameObject. In this you can create some sort of structure to hold different ads or however you plan to populate the ads. Then you can customize the way the ads will be displayed. Will it be random? Will it happen sequentially? Are there different types of ads?
4. Create logic to disable the gameobject based on a timer or by way of a close button.

If you get around to coding and have trouble, then please feel free to ask about the coding. Also, check out the Unity Forums for questions specific to Unity.